# What is the difference between 'Local port' and 'Source port' in inet_sock.h in Linux kernel source code?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

I'm confused about the difference between the varaible `inet_num` and `inet_sport` in file `linux/include/net/inet_sock.h`, and the document just says one is 'local port', and the other is 'source port'.

I print them to the terminal and in every sock the inet_num and inet_sport are different. And I can't find any more document about that.

```c
/* linux/include/net/inet_sock.h */

/** struct inet_sock - representation of INET sockets
 *
 * @sk - ancestor class
 * @pinet6 - pointer to IPv6 control block
 * @inet_daddr - Foreign IPv4 addr
 * @inet_rcv_saddr - Bound local IPv4 addr
 * @inet_dport - Destination port
 * @inet_num - Local port
 * @inet_saddr - Sending source
 * @uc_ttl - Unicast TTL
 * @inet_sport - Source port
 * @inet_id - ID counter for DF pkts
 * @tos - TOS
 * @mc_ttl - Multicasting TTL
 * @is_icsk - is this an inet_connection_sock?
 * @uc_index - Unicast outgoing device index
 * @mc_index - Multicast device index
 * @mc_list - Group array
 * @cork - info to build ip hdr on each ip frag while socket is corked
 */
```

What do they stand for? What is the difference between them? What is their use?

Answer (score 0):

inet_num   - Local port in host byte-order / protocol type.

```
         For TCP/UDP sockets - it is a local port

         Linux allocates the local port from the rage defined by user or   
         initialized by kernel at boot

         https://ma.ttias.be/linux-increase-ip_local_port_range-tcp-port-range/

         For RAW sockets/other protocols (where sport is not req)- protocol type
```

inet_sport - The source port in network byte-order. This is the port you see in
             packet.

```
         inet_sport = hton(inet_num)
```